# Retrieving unabbreviated story through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you look at this [comment](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=200312702164_10151521685107165?fields=story) on the Graph API explorer, the story is abbreviated and its full content is unavailable. Is there any way to easily retrieve the full information of comments like this? Or will they always be unexposed?

```
    {
  "story": "\"We have no technology...\" on Ken Fowler's post on Moodagent's wall.",
  "id": "200312702164_10151521685107165",
  "created_time": "2013-03-11T11:39:01+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into facebook rss. Here is a link to an example that has output so you can see if it fits your needs.

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=5791561181

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think RSS will solve this issue (retrieving content of comments)